# How to create field with dynamic label name in odoo 11?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

[image]I want to get month name in field label.When I select 'June' should be created with Label name Jun1,Jun2 and if I select 'March' should be created with Label name Mar1,Mar2,...Mar31.

Thanks Zar Zar

Comment: I think you could do this with the `name_get()` method of your model, but I will need more details to guide you further. What model is this you are working with? if it's a custom model: what fields are you using and what migth the view look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like :

```
<label for="day" string="jun1" attrs="{'invisible': [('month','=',June)]}"/>
<label for="day" string="jun2" attrs="{'invisible': [('month','=',June)]}"/>
......
 <label for="day" string="Feb1" attrs="{'invisible': [('month','=',February)]}"/>
<label for="day" string="Feb2" attrs="{'invisible': [('month','=',February)]}"/>
```

and go on